# iOS Custom Gesture Recognizer works only first time

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use the checkmark gesture recognizer example in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2) but it only works the first time I make the gesture. After recognized it, it doesn't work again.

I'm using the following code:

CheckmarkGestureRecognizer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface Checkmark2GestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer {
    BOOL strokeUp ;
}


- (void)reset;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) UIGestureRecognizerState state;
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGPoint midPoint;
@end
```

CheckmarkGestureRecognizer.m

```
#import "Checkmark2GestureRecognizer.h"


@implementation Checkmark2GestureRecognizer

@synthesize state;
@synthesize midPoint;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
            NSLog(@"began");
    strokeUp = NO;
    if ([touches count] != 1) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;
    CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];
    if (!strokeUp) {
        // on downstroke, both x and y increase in positive direction
        if (nowPoint.x >= prevPoint.x && nowPoint.y >= prevPoint.y) {
            self.midPoint = nowPoint;
            // upstroke has increasing x value but decreasing y value
        } else if (nowPoint.x >= prevPoint.x && nowPoint.y <= prevPoint.y) {
            strokeUp = YES;
        } else {
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if ((self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) && strokeUp) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
            NSLog(@"Ended");
    }

}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    self.midPoint = CGPointZero;
    strokeUp = NO;
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    NSLog(@"cancelled");
}

- (void)reset {
    [super reset];
    NSLog(@"reset");
    self.midPoint = CGPointZero;
    strokeUp = NO;
}

@end
```

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got similar problem with own gesture recognizer. Seems UIGestureRecognizer doesn't call "reset" method of your class, and doesn't set "state" property to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible.

I know two ways to make it work:

1. You can set state property to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible by yourself in your touchesEnded method. But it seems wrong.
2. You can use state property of UIGestureRecognizer instead of your own state. I.e. use super.state instead of self.state everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code. It works fine with me.
https://github.com/shahidnasrullah/CustomZGestureIOS.git

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `@synthesize state;` line in your implementation. This is already done in the super class.

You also don't have to copy all the definitions from `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h` into you header file. Best is to remove the as well.